# Save Setting Value in Settings File or Database

Tags: c#, settings

Where should I save the setting value like length of member code, separator for member code, in settings file or database? What is pros/cons?
Thanks.

Comment: You might also consider the built-in [Application Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4s6c3a0.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider saving those details in setting files. You can use the scope as "user" so you will be able to modify these values at run time. 
Take a look at this links
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(v=vs.80).aspx 
http://www.dotnetperls.com/settings